# IO Error when enabling https for Nextcloud with Let's Encrypt

Tags: ubuntu, https, lets-encrypt, nextcloud

I'm trying to enable HTTPS for Nextcloud using Let's Encrypt on my Ubuntu server. However, I get an IO error (Error number 13) saying permission was denied to the file `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini`. I've used `chown` to make the file accessible for my user, but I still get the same error.

`~$ sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt
...
An unexpected error occurred:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini'
Please see the logfile '/tmp/tmpHx2bbg' for more details.`

The log file contains the exact same error as the error given in the terminal.

Comment: share logfile contents also.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using nextcloud-snap.
If yes, this seems to be following issue: https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/569

To fix this for now, simply move/rename `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini`.

Alternatively you could switch to the beta channel.

The fix to this problem is going to be implemented in the next stable nextcloud-snap version.